# How can I re-structure my repository in Git?

Tags: git, github

I am currently working under this work directory which has some codes in it ( lets say 'work/(some_codes') ). Now, I would like to re-structure or rather re-arrange this folder to accommodate for my second set of code. I know want the directory to look like 'work/work1/(some_codes)' and 'work/work2/(new_codes)'. How can I do that ?

Comment: ...move the files to new folders and commit?

Comment: Just run `git mv work work1` and commit the changes.

Comment: You mean, you want to move a folder inside another folder? What's the problem?

Comment: it depends on what you mean, and what the context is here. Are you trying to have a seperate copy of the same code to work on? Is it a completely different module? I think you're thinking of branches here though

Comment: not branches. entirely different set of codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [git mv](http://githowto.com/moving_files) command to move all your existing code to the *work1* directory (which you'll have to create and add to git beforehand).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply move your files in local, make a commit and push to remote branch ? Git will automatically re-arrange your remote files like the locales ones.

Comment: Git won't do anything to any remotes until you push to them.

Comment: When i say 'make a commit', I mean make a commit and push it to corresponding remote branch.